# Python Error on import statement : SyntaxError VS ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, import

If i launch 2 import statement with some fake names

i get 2 differents responses from python interpreter

I get these error:

- `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
- `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...`

The only difference is that the second import contain some digit after a dot.

What makes the different error with 2 inexistant files and path ?

Why python doesn't return only one `Error message ModuleNotFoundError` ?

Why python return a `SyntaxError` because of the presence of digit after the dot ?

[different import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mzrD.png)

Comment: `1` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Thanks, so how can we manage import with directory that begin with a digit and that cannot be renamed ?

I have seen that importlib is able to do this, but i dont know if it is a good practice.

Comment: Good practice would be to name your package something different.

Comment: Sure I suppose so, but i'm not in charge on this.
That is why i'm using importlib that seems to be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that `1` is not a valid identifier. Therefore, there is an error in the syntax, causing the `SyntaxError` you see. The first import is correct in terms of syntax, however your program could not find the import.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you cannot name variables or functions starting with a number (1 in this case).

Python will assume that randomeazeay0.a.b.c are all valid, but when you try to import randomeazeay0.a.b.c.`1` it will raise a SyntaxError as that supposed function or variable's name cannot start with a number.